# Align PsPicture to the top in minipage

Tags: align, minipage, pspicture

In the following MWE, I would like to align the pspicture to the top of the text. Using raisebox{-\totalheight+.5\baselineskip} seems to work, but still there's a small gap. How can I remove it?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,DIV=15,oneside,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-circ}
\usepackage{pst-coil}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}
\onehalfspacing
%Minipage 1
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\textwidth}
\textbf{Versuch:} Eine Spule wird an eine regelbare Spannungsquelle angeschlossen. Mithilfe eines Ampèremeters wird die Stromstärke gemessen. Das Teslameter dient zur Messung der magnetischen Flussdichte im Inneren der Spule.
\end{minipage}}\hfill
%Minipage 2
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.37\textwidth}
\raisebox{-\totalheight+.5\baselineskip}{
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{pspicture}
\pnode(0,0){A}
\pnode(4,0){B}
\pnode(4,3){C}
\pnode(0,3){D}
\multidipole(A)(B)
\battery[variable]{}
\circledipole[labeloffset=0]{\Large\textbf{A}}.
\wire(D)(A)
\wire(B)(C)
\pscoil[coilarmA=0.1,coilarmB=0.1,coilwidth=0.5,coilheight=0.75](C)(D){}
\psline[linewidth=2pt](-1,3)(1.3,3)
\psframe[linewidth=0.5pt,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=gray!40](-2,3.2)(-1,2.8)
\psframe[linewidth=0.3pt,fillcolor=white](-1.9,3.1)(-1.4,2.9)
\rput[l](-1.3,3){T}
\end{pspicture}}}
\end{minipage}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Besides, is the there a better way to use raisebox (instead of \baselineskip for example, somewhere I read about \strutbox ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to align the `\fbox`es, align the `\fbox`es.  Note, the `[t]` option of `minipage` aligns the first baseline, which isn't always the same distance from the top of a line of text (adding a \strut to the beginning helps).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,DIV=15,oneside,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-circ}
\usepackage{pst-coil}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}
\onehalfspacing
%Minipage 1
\raisebox{-\height}{\fbox{\begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}
\textbf{Versuch:} Eine Spule wird an eine regelbare Spannungsquelle angeschlossen. Mithilfe eines Ampèremeters wird die Stromstärke gemessen. Das Teslameter dient zur Messung der magnetischen Flussdichte im Inneren der Spule.
\end{minipage}}}\hfill
%Minipage 2
\raisebox{-\height}{\fbox{
\begin{minipage}{0.37\textwidth}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{pspicture}
\pnode(0,0){A}
\pnode(4,0){B}
\pnode(4,3){C}
\pnode(0,3){D}
\multidipole(A)(B)
\battery[variable]{}
\circledipole[labeloffset=0]{\Large\textbf{A}}.
\wire(D)(A)
\wire(B)(C)
\pscoil[coilarmA=0.1,coilarmB=0.1,coilwidth=0.5,coilheight=0.75](C)(D){}
\psline[linewidth=2pt](-1,3)(1.3,3)
\psframe[linewidth=0.5pt,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=gray!40](-2,3.2)(-1,2.8)
\psframe[linewidth=0.3pt,fillcolor=white](-1.9,3.1)(-1.4,2.9)
\rput[l](-1.3,3){T}
\end{pspicture}}
\end{minipage}}}
\end{document}
```